# Is there a way to efficiently store a sequence of enum values in Java?

Tags: java, collections, enums

I'm looking for a way to encode a sequence of enum values in Java that packs better than one object reference per element.  In fantasy-code:

```
List<MyEnum> list = new EnumList<MyEnum>(MyEnum.class);
```

In principle it should be possible to encode each element using `log2(MyEnum.values().length)` bits per element.  Is there an existing implementation for this, or a simple way to do it?

It would be sufficient to have a class that encodes a sequence of numbers of arbitrary radix (i.e. if there are 5 possible enum values then use base 5) into a sequence of bytes, since a simple wrapper class could be used to implement `List<MyEnum>`.

I would prefer a general, existing solution, but as a poor man's solution I might just use an array of longs and radix-encode as many elements as possible into each long.  With 5 enum values, 27 elements will fit into a long and waste only ~1.3 bits, which is pretty good.

*Note: I'm not looking for a set implementation.  That wouldn't preserve the sequence.*

Comment: I don't think this is easily doable for "in memory" elements aside from "treating as unboxed primitives" - couldn't even use a standard generic collection. Now, if talking about a bitstream serialization format ..

Comment: If you need space efficiency at this level, Java is not the right language. You could consider a JNI extension to accomplish something like this. I've never heard of one before.

Comment: Yes, having a class that encodes a sequence of numbers of arbitrary radix into a sequence of bytes would solve the problem, but I don't know of any such class.  My best guess is to leverage BigInteger and deal with the performance penalty.

Comment: @Sam See ByteBuffers, fwiw, although seems like too much work .. will this *really* make/break the program?

Comment: ByteBuffer would reduce the memory usage down to 1 byte per element, but can't go below that.  To do better, with for example 5 enum values you could encode 3 elements into 1 byte by using base 5: elem1.ordinal() + 5*elem2.ordinal() + 25*elem3.ordinal(), for a total of 125 possible values.  This is better, but is there a general solution that doesn't waste that last 1+ bit and generalizes to arbitrary radix?

Answer (score 2):

You can store bits in an int (32 bits, 32 "switches"). But aside from the exercise value, what's the point?- you're really talking about a very small amount of memory. A better question might be, why do you want to save a few bytes in enum references? Other parts of your program are likely to be using much more memory.

If you're concerned with transferring data efficiently, you could consider leaving the Enums alone but using custom serialization, though again, it'd be an unusual situation where it'd be worth the effort.

Comment: I'm planning to store a huge number of strings of enums, so the memory usage is significant.

Comment: How many values are there of the enum type?  I'm still dubious that this is likely to be worthwhile at all.

Answer (score 2):

One object reference typically occupies one 32-bit or 64-bit word.  To do better than that, you need to convert the enum values into numbers that are smaller than 32 bits, and hold them in an array.

Converting to a number is as simple as calling `getOrdinal()`.  From there you could:

- cast to a `byte` or `short`, then represent the sequence as an array of byte / short values, or
- use a suitable compression algorithm on the array of `int` values.

Of course, all of this comes at the cost of making your code more complicated.  For instance you cannot make use of the collection APIs, and you have to do your own sequence management.  I doubt that this will be worth it unless you have to deal with very large sequences or huge numbers of sequences.

---

> In principle it should be possible to encode each element using `log2(MyEnum.values().length)` bits.

In fact you *may* be able to do better than that ... by compressing the sequences.  It depends on how much redundancy there is.